I want the contents of one div to grow or shrink with pinching, everything else to remain at a fixed size
I have a page with a button bar and 3 tabs, each with class .tabcontent, intended for use on an Android phone with Chrome.
Tabs have display=none until selected when display=block or display=inline-block.  I've tried both.
2 tabs contain maps where Leaflet takes care of which tiles are displayed. One map tab has its own button bar overlaid on the map.
The third tab has various divs, one of which can contain any of text, image or iframe. That div has a class of .legend.
Ideally I want to set the page to have a viewport with "user-scalable=no" but be able to resize (pinch to zoom) the contents of the legend div only. However I've failed to achieve that and concluded it's probably not possible.
So setting "user-scalable=yes" I am attempting to keep all but one div at fixed size while enabling pinch to zoom in just the legend div. Reading suggests that setting
.tabcontent {
position: fixed;
max-width: 100vw; 
max-height: 100vh;
overflow: auto;
}

ought to prevent pinch to zoom, but it doesn't.
In the CSS for .tabcontent I have tried various combinations of the following, but in all cases pinching anywhere on the screen resizes everything.
position: relative;, position: fixed;, position: absolute;, width: 100%;, max-width: 100%;, max-width: 300px;, max-height: 600px;, width: 100vw;, height: 100vh;, min-width: 100vw;, min-height: 100vh;, max-width: 100vw;, max-height: 100vh;, max-width: fit-content;, box-sizing: border-box;, box-sizing: content-box;, resize: none;, overflow: auto;, overflow: hidden;
I've also tried using touch-action: pan-x pan-y; on all the divs where I don't want pinch to zoom, and re-enabling it on the one I do.
It doesn't re-enable properly, and anyway zooms everything on the screen, not just the contents of the legend div.
I want the contents of one div to grow or shrink with pinching, everything else to remain at a fixed size.  What should I do?
ps to head off the "don't do this" advice: this page is likely to have about 3 users, all of us elderly and with failing eyesight. It's all plenty big enough to read except the various legends which the user needs to be able to control.
Edited to add
I have made a Codepen to illustrate my problem at https://codepen.io/perplexed24/pen/yLrmVao
The pink box should not change size but its contents should be zoomable.  Contents is selectable in JS between text and image.
The contents of the grey area and the orange bar and its buttons should not change size.
Different behaviours can be seen by changing what is commented out in CSS. I cannot find a working combination of touch-action and other settings.
My initial plan was to set the page to user-scalable=no and then embed all legend content in an iframe with it's own viewport set to user-scalable=yes.
However that doesn't work, despite MDN describing iframes as an "embedded browsing context (with) its own document" the iframe viewport setting is not respected.
What am I missing?

Does it have to be with pinching? As it’s a small group of users could some other method be agreed? E.g. a button or a triple tap.

I'd much prefer pinch.  It'll be offered to a wider group, only a few are likely to be interested but I don't know which ones.

What will be offered to the people who need to expand the other bits in order those them?

Usability.
Expansion pushes controls off the screen, to no purpose.
Expanding one part of the maps screen makes all the controls unreachable, with no way to get them back because Leaflet handles all the rest of the content.
The only way round that is to use the Chrome menu to reload the page.
The screen areas I want to remain at fixed size amounts to a few unchanging buttons. Have a look at the Google Maps app, none of the control area can be resized because there is no need to do so.

Thanks, that makes the requirement clearer. You can implement your own pinch zoom. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action (which mentions maps specifically) for how to switch off the default browser zoom.

Thanks, but as I tried to say initially, pinching on any touch-action enabled div causes the whole visible area to expand, not just the contents of that div.
So restricting touch-action on the buttons div will ensure that pinching on that has no effect but the buttons still change size when the unrestricted legends div is pinched.
I want to lock all div sizes, including the buttons and legend container, and only zoom the contents of the legend container.

I think you have to do it the other way round. Disable the pinch action completely (see the link I gave) and then add code to implement your own.

I'm grateful for your assistance.  I've edited my question with a Codepen to illustrate the problem.

Please show us the code you have tried to implement pinch zoom on that element.

Having corrected my misunderstanding of what you wrote I've found the pinchzoom.js library and other resources, which do everything I need. Thankyou, I am very grateful.
